# AWS Translate Php sdk missing field but not request in documentation

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-translate

I am having an unusual problem with aws sdk on the AWS Translate service.

I need to dynamically translate some response messages, but I get this error.

```
$currentLanguage = 'es';
// If the TargetLanguageCode is not "en", the SourceLanguageCode must be "en".
$targetLanguage= 'en';
$textToTranslate = 'El AWS SDK for PHP versión 3 permite a los desarrolladores de PHP utilizar Amazon Web Services en su código PHP y crear aplicaciones y software robustos utilizando servicios como Amazon S3, Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon Glacier, etc. Puede empezar rápidamente instalando el SDK mediante Composer (solicitando el paquete aws/aws-sdk-php) o descargando el archivo aws.zip o aws.phar independiente';
try {
$translate = $this->aws_utils->getTranslate();
$result = $translate->translateText(array(
'SourceLanguageCode' => $currentLanguage,
'TargetLanguageCode' => $targetLanguage,
'Text' => $textToTranslate
));
}catch (AwsException $e) {
// output error message if fails
var_dump($e->getMessage());die;
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/API_TranslateText.html

As per the documentation I pass the parameters to the SDK service correctly but I get this error 500:
Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the TranslateText operation:
[TranslatedText] is missing and is a required parameter

Does anyone know the problem? That field shouldn't be there completely

Comment: So where are you actually specifying which text to translate? According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/php-translate-TranslateText.php.html, the `translateText` method appears to take _three_ parameters, you passed only two.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong to paste here on stackoverflow .. I updated the question but the problem persists inserting what was already there.. @AWS PS When I also insert the "TranslatedText" parameter the error becomes 400 .... It is very strange, it seems that it wants that parameter but it should only be a property of the response

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to

```
$currentLanguage = 'es';
// If the TargetLanguageCode is not "en", the SourceLanguageCode must be "en".
$targetLanguage= 'en';
$textToTranslate = 'El AWS SDK for PHP versión 3 permite a los desarrolladores de PHP utilizar Amazon Web Services en su código PHP y crear aplicaciones y software robustos utilizando servicios como Amazon S3, Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon Glacier, etc. Puede empezar rápidamente instalando el SDK mediante Composer (solicitando el paquete aws/aws-sdk-php) o descargando el archivo aws.zip o aws.phar independiente';
try {
$translate = $this->aws_utils->getTranslate();
$result = $translate->translateText(array(
'SourceLanguageCode' => $currentLanguage,
'TargetLanguageCode' => $targetLanguage,
'Text' => $textToTranslate, 

));
}catch (AwsException $e) {
// output error message if fails
var_dump($e->getMessage());die;
}
```

and it should work

Comment: Actually, I was wrong to paste here on stackoverflow .. I updated the question but the problem persists inserting what was already there..

@AWS PS When I also insert the "TranslatedText" parameter the error becomes 400 ....
It is very strange, it seems that it wants that parameter but it should only be a property of the response